# Update boolean field in DE if field exists in another DE

Tags: marketing-cloud, query

I'm trying to update a boolean field (true or false) if 'Email' and 'ID' matches in another DE. 'Email' and 'ID' can sometimes exist in both DEs but not always. I've written 2 queries for this flag to run in an automation but I would like to perform this in 1 query if possible. Is there a better way to do this? Thanks in advance. Here is my code for query 1:

```
SELECT a.[id]
, a.[Email]
, 'False' as club_closed
FROM [DE1] a
WHERE club_closed IS NULL
  AND a.[Email] NOT IN
             (SELECT [EMAIL] 
               FROM [DE2])
```

Code for query 2:

```
SELECT a.[id]
, a.[Email]
, 'True' as club_closed
FROM [DE1] a
WHERE club_closed IS NULL
  AND a.[Email] IN
             (SELECT [EMAIL] 
               FROM [DE2])
```

Comment: Thanks @Gortonington. Its not more than maybe 10k rows. I am having trouble with the true/false flag appending to the target DE (which is DE1) so I thought I would join them. I really can't figure out why it isn't working. Is there another way to write the query for this type of task?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should be able to literally just union them. But honestly if you are looking at a high volume, it might be better to keep it separated to account for the 30 min timeout limit.

```sql
SELECT a.[id] , a.[Email] , 'False' as club_closed
FROM [DE1] a
WHERE club_closed IS NULL 
AND a.[Email] NOT IN (SELECT [EMAIL] FROM [DE2])

UNION

SELECT a.[id] , a.[Email] , 'True' as club_closed 
FROM [DE1] a 
WHERE club_closed IS NULL 
AND a.[Email] IN (SELECT [EMAIL] FROM [DE2])
```